# Trimming Carbonite log files

Tags: windows-xp, logging, carbonite

I have a Windows XP machine that I need to last for just a *little* bit longer. 75 GB doesn't go as far as it used to and I'm trying to recover some disk space. (Adding a drive to this thing is not an option, nor is replacing the existing drive.)

I see that a couple of Carbonite log files are upwards of 800 MB and 300 MB in size. I've been using Carbonite since 2007 and there are entries in the logs going back that far. (I don't know why the app wouldn't be built to auto-trim them.)

Anyway, what's going to get screwed up if I delete these log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your not sure whether it is safe to delete a file, try renaming it first (I append ".old" to change the name). That lets you check if the missing file will have an adverse effect on your system. If there's a problem you can rename it back. If everything continues normally, you can be pretty sure you can safely delete it. My guess is that Carbonite will recreate new log files and continue forward.

I believe the log files are used for the “View History” option and Carbonite might ask for them if you need technical support. But I don't *think* deleting them will have an effect on your backups. But try what I said to be sure.

**As an aside**, take a look at *this* program: [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). It *really* helps me visually find files and directories that I've long forgotten which take up a lot of space on my system.

Comment: I have used WinDirStat (and some other drive visualization apps) to track down deleteable files. I'll try your suggestion.